# Yii 2 как подключить авторизацию через AD LDAP

Tags: yii2, composer, ldap, active-directory

есть желание подключить авторизацию через ad ldap. попробовал https://github.com/edvler/yii2-adldap-module

получил

> Problem 1
>
> - Installation request for edvlerblog/yii2-adldap-module v1.0.0 -> satisfiable by edvlerblog/yii2-adldap-module[v1.0.0].
> - edvlerblog/yii2-adldap-module v1.0.0 requires adldap/adldap v4.0-stable -> no matching package found.

как понимаю, нужно еще и это установить: https://github.com/adldap/adLDAP/

текущая версия *adldap 5*. установить 4ю версию не могу. получаю:

> Problem 1
>
> - The requested package adldap/adldap 4.0.4 could not be found.

как быть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

composer.json нужно указать репозитарий и версию

```
   "repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/adldap/adLDAP"
    }
],
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.4.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2": ">=2.0.5",
    "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "*",
    "miloschuman/yii2-highcharts-widget": "*",
   "adldap/adldap": "dev-master as 4.0-stable",
    "edvlerblog/yii2-adldap-module": "v1.0.0"

},
```

решение http://des1roer.blogspot.ru/2015/07/yii-2-ad-ldap.html

Answer (score 1):

вот вам версия v4.0.4, комиит с которой обозначен одноимённым тегом: https://github.com/adldap/adLDAP/tree/v4.0.4

переключиться на этот коммит после клонирования репозитория можно, например, так:

```
 $ git checkout v4.0.4
```